# rpm -e fails with unpre script error in rpmspec file

Tags: rpm-spec

I have developed a package with rpmbuild with unpre script error. The package on testing successfully installed but now Iam unable to remove the package (even with force option) or nodeps option

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same situation. However I was able to uninstall the package with --noscripts option as in `rpm -e <pkgname> --noscripts`.